# How to change the default rank field from score to other field in solr?

Tags: solr

I want to rank my solr results with field "tstamp" other than score, I Know that it works with q=csdn&sort=tstamp%20asc, but can I change the default field in any configuration file(such as solrconfig.xml), other than set the url for each request?

Comment: Sure, set sort in a requesthandler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr lets you define [*requestHandlers*](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler) in solrconfig.xml. These are HTTP endpoints with a specific hard-coded configuration. Specifically, for a search endpoint, you would define something like:

```
<requestHandler name="/timesort" class="solr.SearchHandler">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="sort">tstamp asc</str>
     </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

(copy paste the built in select handler and change what you need to)

Then you just query as follows:

```
http://yourSolr:8983/solr/yourCollection/timesort?q=csdn
```

And the default sort will be my `tstamp asc`. You can override the sort if need be from the query. If you want to ignore anything thats passed to the request handler and always sort by tstamp, put the sort parameter in *invariants*.